# Hide or disable navigator handles in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I want to disable the use of navigator in highcharts but still show it as "full" small chart.

Is it possible?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can hide them in callback: http://jsfiddle.net/nX37D/

But user still will have possibility to change extremes by using handles (even if they are invisible). To change that behavior, you will need to edit sources.

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', options, function (chart) {
    var handles = chart.scroller.handles;
    setTimeout(function () {
        handles[0].hide();
        handles[1].hide();
    }, 1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to hide them within the API is:

```
    navigator: {
        handles: {
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            borderColor: 'transparent'
        }
    },
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nX37D/).