# How to disable zoom in Navigator?

Tags: highcharts

I want to disable zoom from my HighStock chart navigator's. I mean, don't allow the user to resize the selector in the navigator, just drag it.

I have tried settings axisX min and max but it only set the initial values. I also found [xAxis#minRange](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.minRange%20%22%22) but there is not an option like `xAxis#maxRange` so I can set min and max range to the same value to avoid zooming.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can [hide them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21331109/hide-or-disable-navigator-handles-in-highcharts) and [use setExtremes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125572/disabling-handlebars-in-highstock-charts-navigator).

Comment: Yes but user is still able to move them accidentally :/

Comment: Yes, that is what the setExtremes would be for. Keeping the size the same. Otherwise you probably have to make changes to it's behavior by altering the navigator handle source code to remove them completely.

Comment: Just tried it and it's not working :/ I can still zoom and behavior gets weird, it seems the framework doesn't detect when I release mouse button and can't do anything else

Comment: You need to catch setExtremes and afterSetExtremes and update your range, becaseue max zoom is not avaiable.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the `zoomType: 'none',` property.